# Where are the cache files of NSFetchedResultsController located?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am trying to see if cache files are successfully created but can't find their location on the disk (neither on simulator nor iPhone device)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are located in

```
${APP_DIRECTORY}/Library/Caches/.CoreDataCaches
```

Comment: I checked using Finder and .CoreDataCaches is not there.
Under Caches I have only two items: AccessToMigrationLock and AccountMigrationInProgress... In the Simulator I have a folder named snapshots.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to unix. A filename with a dot prefix will be hidden in finder and at the console. By using the Terminal application and doing a `ls -la` you will see the directory.